# Speed control of DC motors and voltage being lost

Tags: transistors, motor, dc-motor, motordriver

I am experimenting with speed control of DC motors using L298N and TB6612FNG. In order to compare the two chips I am supplying the motor with the same voltage in both cases \$ V_m = 4.7V \$. For the case of TB6612FNG when driving the motor at full speed, I measure the output voltage at the pins of the chip and I measure around \$ V_{out} = 3V \$ and for the case of L298N I measure \$ V_{out} = 1.5V \$. Is this difference due to the fact that BJTs (inside L298N) have a forward voltage drop of around \$ 0.7V\$ and bacause two of operate we get a total forward voltage drop of around \$1.4V\$ where in the case of TB6612FNG MOSFETs have really low forward voltage drop ? And my other question is where is the voltage being lost in both cases ? I mean I supply \$4.7V\$ and in the one case I get \$3V\$ maximum and in the other case I get \$1.5V\$ maximum. Where is the remaining voltage being lost ?

**EDIT:** Connections are pretty simple and basic. I got a laboratory power supply (voltage lost while transmitting power is pretty low - only \$ 0.007V \$) from which the motor drivers (so the motors) are powered and I have an Arduino UNO sending the PWM pulses to the motor drivers. In order to control the duration of the pulses I got a simple linear potentiometer wired up to the arduino.

Comment: L298's are just pretty bad. Not going to comment on the other without a schematic.

Comment: How much **current** does the motor draw when controlled by the TB6612, and how much when connected directly to 4.7V? Where is the 4.7V coming from?

Comment: When connected directly to \$ 4.7V \$ (which comes from a bench power supply - pretty decent only \$ 0.007V \$ are lost) the motor draws around \$ 3.4A \$ while when controlled by the TB6612FNG it draws around \$ 1.95A \$ at maximum speed of course.